# How to fix issue with firestore collection snapshot

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to order my messages collection from Firebase from newest to oldest. But my messages display randomly once after the last and once before the last.
Despite my final who order my collection by reverse

I've tried to find any subject to orders by realtime but I can't find anything about this on Flutter and Firestore. (Maybe I'm blind or I'm not looking well)

```dart
class MessagesStream extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: _fireStore.collection('messages').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Center(
            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
              backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlueAccent,
            ),
          );
        }
        final messages = snapshot.data.documents.reversed;
        List<MessageBubble> messageBubbles = [];
        for (var message in messages) {
          final messageSender = message.data['sender'];
          final messageText = message.data['text'];

          final currentUser = loggedInUser.email;

          final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
            sender: messageSender,
            text: messageText,
            isMe: currentUser == messageSender,
          );
          messageBubbles.add(messageBubble);
        }
        return Expanded(
          child: ListView(
            reverse: true,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
            children: messageBubbles,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

I add my data into this widget :

```dart
FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      messageTextController.clear();
                      _fireStore.collection('messages').add(
                          {'text': messageText, 'sender': loggedInUser.email});
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
```

Comment: how are you adding your data to firestore *add code*

Comment: `FlatButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      messageTextController.clear();
                      _fireStore.collection('messages').add(
                          {'text': messageText, 'sender': loggedInUser.email});
                    },
                    child: Text(
                      'Send',
                      style: kSendButtonTextStyle,
                    ),
                  ),
` 
I add my data into this widget

Answer (score 2, accepted):

while adding data you can add a  timestamp /server timestamp to your message doc and then use it to arrange your data  example **`"timestamp": Timestamp.now(),`** then query your data **`.orderby('timestamp' ,descending :true)`**

Comment: Thank you it's exactly what I'm looking for ! Now I will try implement it well :D

Comment: I would suggest when using timestamp , to avoid data indexing wrongly you can set a server default time stamp like +0300 GMT .